# Using SQL Like in Jqgrid

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid from guriddo and want to create a query with LIKE in it dynamically. I have the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
if (isset($_SESSION['search']))
{
    $temp = $_SESSION['search'];
    $sql .= " WHERE users.name LIKE %".$temp."%";
}
$grid->SelectCommand = $sql;
```

But this gives me the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%'Adam'% LIMIT 0, 0' at line 9

Comment: `use near '%'Adam'%`: the quotes should be wrapping the wildcards, not the other way around, and use prepared statements instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a quote. It should be

```
$sql .= " WHERE users.name LIKE '%".$temp."%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing single quote `'` around your `Like`

below should work

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
if (isset($_SESSION['search']))
{
    $temp = $_SESSION['search'];
    $sql .= " WHERE users.name LIKE '%".$temp."%'";
}
$grid->SelectCommand = $sql;
```